# What's the name of the type of button that you have to press and hold for current to pass through it?

Tags: switches, button

[image]

I want to build a LED toy gun that lights up when the trigger is pressed. I need a button or switch that only allows current to pass through it only when the button is pressed and held down. What is the name of the type of switch/button I need to help me with this project?

Comment: A momentary switch. You probably want one of the little ones that's often called a tactile switch.

Comment: For a toy gun, probably what's called an "SPST short-lever microswitch." Just google it and look at the Images tab. You'll see lots of good examples there.

Answer (score 2):

A momentary switch has to be held down. This is normal for something like a microswitch or push-button, but is unusual and has to be specified for a lever switch.

This is in contrast to a latching switch, which is operated from one position to another. This is normal for a lever switch, can be found in push-buttons if specified, and is not found in microswitches.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to the above comments and answers that momentary switches come in Normally Closed (NC), and Normally Open (NO). For the toy gun, you would need a Normally Open or NO switch.